# What can I do with the account, if I banned from asking questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I have got banned from asking questions and answers? I have improved some of my questions. Will deleting my answers help?

Thanks

Comment: One thing you should not do is create new accounts to work around a question or answer ban. Just saying.

Comment: Okay, cool. I will remember that @BradLarson